# Page not found (404). No Category matches the given query

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

I am building an Ecommerce site thru Django framework. While creating category section which takes user to individual category to access all its items, following error occurs.

```
Page not found (404)
No Category matches the given query.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/ring/
Raised by:  store.views.category_list
Using the URLconf defined in core.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='all_product']
item/<slug:slug>/ [name='product_detail']
search/<slug:category_slug>/ [name='category_list']
The current path, search/ring/, matched the last one.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Here is the urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'store'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.all_product, name='all_product'),
    path('item/<slug:slug>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
    path('search/<slug:category_slug>/', views.category_list, name='category_list'),
]
```

views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

from .models import  Product, Category

# Create your views here.
def categories(request):
    return {
        'categories': Category.objects.all()
    }


def all_product(request):
    product = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'store/home.html', {'product': product})


def category_list(request, category_slug):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
    product = Product.objects.filter(category=category)
    return render(request, 'store/products/category.html', {'category': category, 'product': product})

def product_detail(request, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug, in_stock=True)
    return render(request, 'store/products/detail.html', {'product': product})
```

models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    
    class meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'
        
        
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('store:category_list', args=[self.slug])
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='product' , on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    created_by= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_creator' )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='admin')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    in_stock = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    
    class meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'products'
        ordering = ('-created',)
        
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('store:product_detail', args=[self.slug])
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And category.html file

```
{% extends "../base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}
{% if category %}{{ category.name }}{% else %}Product{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}


<main>
  <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="pb-3 h5">{{category.name|title}}</div>
      <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-5 g-3">

        {% for product in product %}

        <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm">
          <img class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" src="{{ product.image.url }}">

            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">
                <a class="text-dark text-decoration-none" href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">{{ product.title }}</a>
              </p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <small class="text-muted">5 min read</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        {% endfor %}

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</main>

{% endblock %}
```

Every time i enter '127.0.0.1:8000/search/ring' in url bar ,it raises error for category search mentioned above but it is working fine for product details i.e '127.0.0.1:8000/item/ring'.

Comment: As the error implies there is no `Category` object in your database which has "ring" as its slug.

Comment: Got it. I have been writing '127.0.0.1:8000/search/ring' instead of '127.0.0.1:8000/item/jewelry' in url bar. Jewelry is the Category Slug whereas Ring is one of its item. I have been mixing Url of product_details with Category_slug. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably change `<slug:slug>` and `<slug:category_slug>` to
`<str:slug>` and `<str:category_slug>`
in your urls.py

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: Have you tried removing / at the end of `item/<str:slug>/` and `search/<str:category_slug>/` so it becomes `item/<str:slug>` and `search/<str:category_slug>`?

Comment: I was entering specific item (ring) of a category (jewelry) as category_slug in url bar like I was doing with product_detail. Error is resolved. Thank you.